# Windows 8.1 Media Creation Tool, is Update 3 (KB3000850) included?

Tags: windows-8.1

Microsoft provides an official tool, [Windows Media Creation Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), for downloading Windows 8.1 installation media to an ISO file or USB Key.

Does the media, obtained via this tool, include [Update 3 (KB3000850)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3000850)?

[ISOs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx#searchTerm=windows%208.1%20update%20multiple&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&Architectures=x64&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) available to MSDN subscribers *do* include Update 3, but I can't find any information about what Windows Media Creation Tool gives us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of a total lack of information on the internet, and comments from **Ramhound** that (while appreciated) were not backed up with reference or evidence, I decided to do my own test.

I used the [Windows Media Creation Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) to download Windows 8.1 Pro, and installed it in a Virtual Machine with networking disabled to prevent automatic updates kicking in.

Conclusion: **YES, [Update 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3000850) is included.** It is identified as *KB3000850*. You can see it, along with a bunch of other updates, in *Control Panel - Installed Updates:*

[image: Control Panel, Installed Updates]